# Where am I going wrong in taking this partial derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to use to known relations to derive the Gibbs-Helmholtz equation.

1. $S = -\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_V$
2. $F=E-TS$

Must result in

3. $E = -T^2 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \frac{F}{T}\right)_V$

**My attempt:**

To solve this, I tried working backwards and taking the partial derivative as instructed inside the parentheses, but I don't get the same result as in the equation (2).

$$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \frac{F}{T}\right)_V$$

$$=F \left( \frac{-1}{T^2}\right) + \frac{\partial F}{T}$$

Plugging this back into eq. (3):

$$E = -T^2 \left( F \left( \frac{-1}{T^2}\right) + \frac{\partial F}{T} \right)$$

$$E = F-\left(\partial F\cdot T\right)$$

I know I'm making some sort of mistake somewhere, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
-T^2 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \frac{F}{T}\right)_V=-T^2\left(F \left( \frac{-1}{T^2}\right) + \frac1T\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)=F-T\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}=F+TS=E
$$

Comment: Why is it $\frac{1}{T} \frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$ and not just $\frac{\partial F}{T}$ in your 2nd step? I guess this is the main part of my confusion.

Comment: $\frac{\partial F}{T}$ has no meaning. You need to take the derivative with respect to something.

Comment: Why not? To me it feels like I just applied the product rule for differentiation to the numerator and the denominator separately.

Comment: Well, if you say what $\partial F$ is for you, we can perhaps proceed from there.

Comment: Isn't it just the partial derivative of $F$?

Comment: OK, then your symbol $\partial F$ is the same as $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$ for me. And that is what appears in your equation (1).

Comment: Is the idea that I'm missing here similar to $y=2x \to dy=2dx \to \frac{dy}{dx} = 2$?

Comment: Yes, the same. But since you wrote $\frac{1}{\partial T}$ on the left-hand side, you also need to write it on the other side.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. But I just noticed that your answer resulted in $+TS$ when the original equation is $-TS$.

Comment: Yes, it results in $F+TS$, which according to your equation (2) is equal to $E$.

Comment: Woops!!! You're right, sorry about that!!